# Android Java: cannot resolve symbol already declared

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the this part of code:

```
    final String[] qst = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q1);
    qt.setText(qst[0]);
    respA.setText(qst[1]);
    respB.setText(qst[2]);
    respC.setText(qst[3]);
    respD.setText(qst[4]);
```

and it runs without problem. I want get a array in strings.xml with a question of multiple choise. The problem is i want a random a question, to present on screen.
I thought the best solution for that is randomize a int and pick a question as a function of the entire (because im a noob lol). But when i try the code

```
    final int iqst = 1;
    if (iqst == 1) {
        final String[] qst = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q1);
    }
    qt.setText(qst[0]);
    respA.setText(qst[1]);
    respB.setText(qst[2]);
    respC.setText(qst[3]);
    respD.setText(qst[4]);
```

android studio give a error:
Error:(113, 20) error: cannot find symbol variable qst.

I already searched on internet but i dont figure Why can not I declare an array in an if

Comment: Because the scope of `qst` is in the if block body, so invisible outside. (you should also have a warning)

Comment: It's not available outside of the scope you've declared it in.

Comment: Thanks! it makes sense... I'll look for a way around the problem. 
One of my big problems is that not mastered the English language and it becomes hard to know what to look for sure .
he first thing that I remembered

Comment: Thanks! it makes sense... I'll look for a way around the problem. 
One of my big problems is that not mastered the English language and it becomes hard to know what to look for sure .

The first thing that I remembered is declare qst[] outside of if, but it givemes other error:
Error:(109, 13) error: cannot assign a value to final variable qst.

I have to replace final to another keyword?

I hve tried in a similar form, but When I declared the array , I just assigned a value, and so it gave error . I'm right?

Comment: Hum... I tried several ways and i can resolve the problem... I will past were if anyone have the same problem:
Random r = new Random();
        final int iqst = r.nextInt(2) + 1;

        final String[] qst;

        if (iqst == 1) {
            qst = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q1);
        } else if (iqst == 2) {
            qst = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q2);
        }

        qt.setText(qst[0]);
        respA.setText(qst[1]);
        respB.setText(qst[2]);
        respC.setText(qst[3]);
        respD.setText(qst[4]);
(for two possible questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable qst is in the scope of the if block. It can only be accessible within that if block the way you declared it. A way I would do this is to declare it on the outside, say

```
final int iqst = 1;
String[] qst = null; 
if (iqst == 1) {
    qst = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q1);
}
qt.setText(qst[0]);
respA.setText(qst[1]);
respB.setText(qst[2]);
respC.setText(qst[3]);
respD.setText(qst[4]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! May the gods bless you!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring qst inside if. It is invalid outside the if block